# XML security in world wide web

Tags: xml

Im a newbie in XML and i have some questions

1. Can XML be used in stead of normal database (store data in a tuple and column) in website?
2. XML is built to share information easier (from my understanding) such as can share cross platform and in different language used so Is it secure to store secure data in XML?

thank you so much

Comment: No, I'm just reading about XML and I find it very interesting.I am going to create a website from the beginning so im wondering should i be used all XML as a database since my website will have RSS feature. And It cant be homework question because i'm not in school/university anymore ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use it as a (very simple) datastore.
   If you are using .NET, System.Data.Dataset has good importing and exporting from xml.  And then there's linq to xml which is just great :)
2. It's not secure.  You could encrypt the text before you write to the xml file.... but if you want something secure, you don't want to use an xml file.

Answer (score 1):

1) XML is not a database but a markup language originally intended to markup documents. The language has the ability to describe the contents of its elements but that must be interpreted by some other language. It is used in a db sort of way to describe the contents of a file but it won't retrieve any data without an outside application.

2) XML is cross platform since it's just text. This is one big advantage in that it works everywhere with everything.

Answer (score 1):

"Can XML be used in stead of normal database"

Sure

"store data in a tuple and column"

Sort of. It's hierarchical data rather than relational.

"Is it secure to store secure data in XML"

XML is a file format for a text document. Security is a separate layer outside of the XML document.